# Why does one Excel file respond to changes slower than others?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a Excel 2010 file with 5 worksheets. Each one has very little information with little formatting. At the beginning, it was very fast when saving data (e.g., when inputting a number or text into a cell then pressing Enter for saving it) but now it takes about one second (or even more) that Excel saves the value and jumps to next cell.

I don't use network for Excel and also don't use complicated calculations and Macros/VBA code or animations. Every thing is in its normal (primary) state and I work on one workbook at a time. It loads normally (fast) when opening as well.

Note: The problem doesn't belong to my OS (Windows 7) because when I open a new Microsoft Excel file, saving data is as much fast as it was before in it.

Any idea what is the problem with that file?

Comment: Is this a file from a previous version of Excel? Have you tried to copy the data to a new Excel file to see if the performance issue resolves? Are there any links to external data in any of the sheets?

Comment: No it's a new Excel 2010 file. When I created another new Excel file and copied all data (of that previous one onto that new one) the saving function (slowness) again occurred!

Comment: There must be something in what you copied causing this. Any external links? What functions are you using? If you turn off automatic calculation does the problem go away?

Comment: No links. I haven't learned functions so just use tiny formulas like "=B1*C2". I turned the automatic calculation off, but no difference!

Answer (score 0):

Try the profiler in the [FormulaDesk](http://www.formuladesk.com) add-in. It should be able to tell you exactly where the problems are. Also check for volatile cells (in the profiler) as any dependents of volatile cells also become volatile and get recalculated often if the calculation mode in automatic - which it should be.

*Disclaimer: [FormulaDesk](http://www.formuladesk.com) is my product.*

[image]